# CMake Include Directories not found

Tags: makefile, cmake

I have a library project whose hierarchy looks something like this:

```
Root:
    + src/
        + apple.cpp
        + bananas/
            + bananas.cpp
        ...
    + include/
        + apple.h
        + bananas/
            + bananas.h
        ...
```

I've been using Visual Studio to compile it and it works fine but now I want to diversify it by allowing the library to be compiled using CMake. I've created the following `CMakeLists.txt` file (located in Root):

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)     # Version 2.8 required 

file(GLOB_RECURSE HEADERS               # Fetch all of the Lib's Headers 
   ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/*.h 
   ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/*.hpp 
) 

file(GLOB_RECURSE SOURCES               # Fetch all of the Lib's Srcs 
   ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/*.cpp 
) 

add_library(                            # Create the Library from Srcs 
    HoneycombGameEngine ${SOURCES} 
) 

target_include_directories(             # Add the Headers to the Lib
    HoneycombGameEngine 
    PUBLIC
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
)
```

It compiles with CMake and generates its files, however when I run `make` to actually compile the library, I get an error in the `bananas.cpp` file (first file it chooses to compile) that it cannot find the `bananas.h` header file. If it is relevant, the `bananas.cpp` include header statement looks like this:

```
#include "..\..\include\bananas\bananas.h"
```

I'm not exactly sure what I'm doing wrong, this my first time using CMake so I mostly wrote my CMakeLists file using bits and examples from the internet. Anything that could point me in the right direction and help me solve this issue is much appreciated.

Comment: `make VERBOSE=1` will give you an exact command line used to compile a given `.cpp` file.

Comment: Hopefully your target platform is MS Windows, because backslashes instead of slashes in paths are unsupported in many systems

Comment: and that has fixed it... thank you for your help, it's not my code, though to be honest i was not aware that backslashes are undefined for includes... thanks for your help and for teaching me something new.

Comment: @user3159253 even on windows, I am not sure that for example mingw can handle backslashed instead of slashes. To user3250889: try to replace all "\" with "/" in include pathes

Answer (score 1):

You are only get all .h inside include directory.
Bananas.h is inside bananas directory. Then you have to use something like it:

```
file(GLOB_RECURSE HEADERS               # Fetch all of the Lib's Headers 
   ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/*.h 
   ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/bananas/*.h  
)
```